# What does `1587-163` mean from the IBM XL C/C++ compiler

Tags: c++, xlc

I've compiled some code with the IBM XL C/C++ compiler v13.1.6 (13.01.0006.0000). My program is ending by printing the message

```
1587-163
```

Without any additional information.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IBM XL C/C++ compiler might issue a *runtime* error message code without additional information if a nondefault method of installation or configuration was used. `1587` means the error was from the SMP *runtime* component.

In this case, set the `NLSPATH` environment variable to point to the location of the message catalogue. Find more information at [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSXVZZ_13.1.6/com.ibm.xlcpp1316.lelinux.doc/install/setnlspath.html).

After `NLSPATH` is set, you should have a complete error message such as:

`1587-163 Error encountered while attempting to execute on the target device 1.  The program will stop.`

Comment: I had to use `export NLSPATH=/sw/summitdev/xl/20171023-beta/msg/en_US/smprt.cat`, but that seems to have got things working. Thanks!